# After compiling PHP from source are the devel libraries still needed?

Tags: php, linux, compilation

After compiling PHP from source are the devel libraries still needed?
For example, I am building a newer version of PHP from source than is on our dev servers. I installed alot of [extension i.e. mysql, postgresql, curl, etc]-devel packages in order for the configure from the dev server setup to work. Do i still need these after php has compiled? For example could I make a distro and then distribute the PHP distro to another server without needing these devel dependencies?

I am a bit of a noob to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to ship the devel-libraries.
But my advice is to take some time and learn how the build system of your linux distribution works. And then build a new php *package* that can be installed by the package manager.
Take a look at how the "original" php packages were built for the distribution. Most likely you can simply copy and edit the existing rule file(s) and then make a new version of that package. This way you take advantage of the dependency mechanisms and the package manager will not remove/overwrite your version so easily when an update shows up in the "official" repositories.